# Add a row in Woocommerce order edit pages after customer adress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I want to add a new row link the screen shot below to write some meta values to it.

How to add new row in admin order detail page?

I have spent a long time looking but the only locations I can find are for the three columns (marked in red).

[image: please see screen image below]

Any advice greatly welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with ease using this custom hooked function example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'admin_custom_row_after_order_addresses', 10, 1 );
function admin_custom_row_after_order_addresses( $order ){
    ?>
        </div></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!-- new custom section row -->
        <div class="order_data_column_container">
            <div class="order_data_column_wide">
                <h3><?php _e("My Custom row title"); ?></h3>
                <!-- custom row paragraph -->
                <p><?php
                    _e("Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.");
                ?></p>
    <?php
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your help this works perfectly. I did get something working similar using css but instead I set the three columns to be 100% wide and they then stacked. Your solution doesn't affect the three columns above the new row.

Comment: @jzxz234 Yes this solution create a completely new row at 100% width like in your screenshot. Thanks :)